# how to add animation to xPage repeat control items?

Tags: javascript, css, dojo, xpages

The idea is to let users to sign in for some e.g. events and submit the form. Once form is submitted it shows all events chosen as animated list so items appear with a chain animation. Assume I have to use a repeat control. So here is my page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">
    <xp:this.beforePageLoad><![CDATA[#{javascript:viewScope.AAA = new Array();
viewScope.AAA.push("value1");
viewScope.AAA.push("value2");
viewScope.AAA.push("value3");
viewScope.AAA.push("value4");
viewScope.AAA.push("value5");
viewScope.AAA.push("value6");
viewScope.AAA.push("value7");
viewScope.AAA.push("value8");
viewScope.AAA.push("value9");}]]></xp:this.beforePageLoad>
    <xp:button value="Label" id="button1">
        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="false">
            <xp:this.script>
                <xe:dojoFadeOut node="repeatDiv" duration="100"></xe:dojoFadeOut>
            </xp:this.script>
        </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:button>
    <xp:br></xp:br>
    <xp:br></xp:br>
    <xp:repeat id="repeat1" rows="30" value="#{javascript:viewScope.AAA}"
        indexVar="idxname" repeatControls="true" var="cname">
        <xp:div id="repeatDiv" style="background-color:rgb(128,255,128)">
            <xp:text escape="true" id="computedField1" value="#{javascript:cname}">
            </xp:text>
        </xp:div>
    </xp:repeat>
</xp:view>
```

By pressing on the button I want to unhide the repeat but show all items with chain animation. So far it kinda works just for first item in the repeat. Does anybody have feasible solution? It doesn't have to be a repeat. Any list of items/labels/computed fields

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you can script the simple action, but I do not know how to do so effectively. Instead I use this type of logic to directly call the dojo.fadeOut animation (or I use a jQuery / bootstrap equivalent.)

One trick is to make sure each of the divs in the repeat is uniquely named in a way that you can easily find them.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xp:view
        xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
        xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">
        <xp:this.beforePageLoad><![CDATA[#{javascript:viewScope.AAA = new Array();
    viewScope.AAA.push("value1");
    viewScope.AAA.push("value2");
    viewScope.AAA.push("value3");
    viewScope.AAA.push("value4");
    viewScope.AAA.push("value5");
    viewScope.AAA.push("value6");
    viewScope.AAA.push("value7");
    viewScope.AAA.push("value8");
    viewScope.AAA.push("value9");}]]>
</xp:this.beforePageLoad>
<xp:scriptBlock>
        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[
dojo.require("dijit.form.Button");

function fadeIt(nodeid){
    dojo.style(nodeid, "opacity", "1");
    var fadeArgs = {
            node: nodeid,
            duration: 2000
      };
      dojo.fadeOut(fadeArgs).play();
   }
 ]]></xp:this.value>
    </xp:scriptBlock>
<xp:br></xp:br>
    <xp:br></xp:br>
    <xp:repeat
        id="repeat1"
        rows="30"
        value="#{javascript:viewScope.AAA}"
        indexVar="idxname"
        repeatControls="true"
        var="cname">
        <xp:div
            style="background-color:rgb(128,255,128)">
            <xp:this.id><![CDATA[${javascript:"repeatDiv" + idxname}]]></xp:this.id>
            <xp:text
                escape="true"
                id="computedField1"
                value="#{javascript:cname}">
            </xp:text>
        </xp:div>
    </xp:repeat>
    <xp:br />
</xp:view>
```

Then the button logic looks like this:

```
<xp:button
        value="Label2"
        id="button2">
        <xp:eventHandler
            event="onclick"
            submit="false">
            <xp:this.script><![CDATA[
var nodeid = "#{id:repeatDiv0}";
var hsecs = 0;
setTimeout("fadeIt('" + nodeid + "');", (hsecs*1000)+1)

nodeid = "#{id:repeatDiv1}";
hsecs += 2;
setTimeout("fadeIt('" + nodeid + "');", (hsecs*1000)+1)

nodeid = "#{id:repeatDiv2}";
hsecs += 2;
setTimeout("fadeIt('" + nodeid + "');", (hsecs*1000)+1)

//  ... and so forth...
]]></xp:this.script>
        </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:button>
```

Happy coding!